# How to change background color of side pane of Kate and Kile?

Tags: kde, colors, theme, kate, kile

I am trying to customize the color scheme of Kile/Kate. I could do it, except I could not find any way to change the color of the side pane such as files, etc.

I prefer dark background, and having dark background in editing space and white background in the left pane is not good for my eyes.

Comment: @Joon does kile use kwrite_part?

Comment: @Joon also out of curiousity did you find a dark theme for kate somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can change it from within Kate, because I think it's like a filebrowser_part or something. Go to *System Settings > Application Appearance > Colors* Try the Zion ( Reversed ) Scheme. I think you can change those colors individually, and obviously you can create a scheme. I wish the makers of kate would realize that dev's like dark backgrounds and facilitate it more.

[image: system settings screenshot]
Here's the resulting appearance of kate

[image: kate dark ( Zion ( Reversed ) Scheme )]

*please note some portions of this are not from the colorscheme but other settings*

Comment: seems I found a [bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=250319)... the toolbar labels shouldn't be that dark.

Comment: thank you for your answer. The problem was I was in Gnome environment in openSUSE 11.3. After I installed kdebase4-workspace package, I could run systemsettings, and change the theme.

-Joon

Comment: @joon: FWIW, you can download kate schemas which will allow the side and editing panes to have a dark background. See: <http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20902/where-to-get-kate-color-schemes> for some links.

Comment: Might I ask where you downloaded the Evening Lilac, Cherry Blossom and related colour schemes please.

Comment: @chandra using Arch-Linux they must be part of a package that is included with the kde-meta package... I'd check your distro for additional theme packages.

Comment: Note that changing the color theme of KDE only doesn't work. I had to change the color sheme in Kate/KWrite/… from "KWrite - default" or similar to "KDE" to get the dark background