# How to change background color of side panels of Kate using i3?

Tags: xorg, graphics, i3, kate

I'm struggling with applying solarized theme onto my i3 on archlinux. It works perfectly in terminals but I can't get to colour kate's side panels.

[image: A kate layout that sucks.]

Changing kate's inner configuration does not work for the panels. For xorg configuration I used [this](https://pastebin.com/WmPjQyrM) file.

Comment: Is this related? https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1641/19818

Answer (score 1):

To edit the colors of kate's panels you have to edit the colors in the Kde system settings. To edit those, open systemsettings5.